# after loading a picture, imageview does not update

Tags: java, android, image

When i press load button, im suppose to go to the galley, choose a picture and then set the imageview img to that picture. The problem is after i choose a picture in galley, the imageview does not update. However, if i press load button a second time, it take a second or two to load the galley and in that time, imageview will load the picture i previously choosen. Can someone help me so i can get imageview to refresh correctly

```
 load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
              Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                try {

                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
                     bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                     img.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                     if (in != null) {
                         in.close();
                     }
                     img.invalidate();

                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }      
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this doesn't work this way :)
You should move your code for loading and setting the bitmap to the `onActivityResult` method. Also it's a very bad practive to catch an instance of Exception - try catching only the respective checked exception here - i.e FileNotFoundException or something -you can delete your try - catch clasuse and afterwards pres `ctrl + 1` in Eclipse while you have selected the `FileInputStream in = new ...` row --> choose the surround with try-catch option and eclipse will auto-generate for you the appropriate catch clause( and here I mean just the proper checked exception to be handled, not the catch clause body :) ).

Comment: thanks, after i put loading and setting bitmap to my onactivityresult, it worked